# Good method to compare time?

Tags: bash, shell, shell-script, date, time

I need to check for the current time and abort the script if it is not proper time of day I am supposed to run it. Also, if anyone else runs it, it should abort.

For example: I need my script to only run if it is started between 10 PM and and 2 AM (a 4 hour window).

Currently I am doing the following. Taking the time with `date +%k%M` and comparing with hard coded numbers

```
#!/bin/sh
currTime=`date +%k%M`
check_time_to_run()
{
    tempTime=$1
    if [ $tempTime -gt 200 -a $tempTime -lt 2200 ]; then 
        echo "Time is between 2 AM and 10 PM. Aborting."
        exit 1
    else
        echo "Time is after 10 PM and before 2 AM. Running normally."
    fi
}

check_time_to_run $currentTime
```

I would like to know if there is any other efficient method with respect to time comparision in `sh` or `bash` ?

Comment: If you need to compare two dates try to convert them to MJD or UNIX time, for example: `date +%s`.

Comment: @Eddy no it's not the date, It's the time I need to compare.

Comment: I think, in seconds it would be better: `currTime=$(date +%s); lower=$(date +%s --date="2:00"); upper=$(date +%s --date="22:00"); if [$currTime -gt $lower -a $currTime -lt $upper]; then` …

Comment: why not put the script in the crontab? this way you ensure that it runs at that specific time

Comment: @Alex It's current in crontab. But I need to avoid if any other user runs it directly. I do want to have them the permissions but the processing the script does is critical which I need to restrict. Hence going for the time check.

Comment: As any user can change the time for a process with [`faketime`](http://www.code-wizards.com/projects/libfaketime/index.html), your script is not very safe. Using lockfiles is probably a better option.

Comment: Looks fine to me. And I agree with @jofel, this is quite insecure. If this is supposed to run with any kind of privilege, a sane setup will just refuse to run a _script_ that is SUD/SGID.

Comment: What are you trying to do this for? Perhaps we can propose a better solution to your problem (as opposed to your question).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That looks perfect to me. What makes you think it should be improved?

Anyway, ways to improve it could be:

- Use a smaller, quicker shell than bash like dash or pdksh.
- use a shell that has date capabilities builtin like `zsh` or `ksh93`
- use `gawk` (which is smaller than bash, but not than dash but could avoid the extra fork):

Example:

```
#! /usr/bin/gawk -f
BEGIN {now = strftime("%k%M")+0; exit(now > 200 && now < 2200)}
```

Comment: ok cool. Just wanted to confirm that what I am doing is not crude or evil. Thanks for the suggestions.

Answer (score 4):

If external tools are allowed you might want to check [`dateutils`](http://www.fresse.org/dateutils/).

Your "script'' becomes:

```
if dtest time --gt '02:00:00' && dtest time --lt '22:00:00'; then
    echo "Time is between 2 AM and 10 PM. Aborting."
fi
```

Disclaimer: I am the author of said tool.